# How to find out actual disk usage?

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

How can I find out the actual disk usage?

I mean which applications are using my hard disk? Also, I would like to see the percentage of the "occupation" of the HDD.

It seems to be a basic question, so it may be a duplicate. However, I wasn't able to find it out in *Ask Ubuntu* or *Google*. (Maybe I use the wrong terminology.)

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Yaron's answer, you should also have a look at `iotop`. It will show you which process does read/write operations to your disk. `sudo iotop` and then press O and you will see that useful information.

Answer (score 1):

**df - report file system disk space usage**

usage:

```
df -h
```

-h - human read-able

**du - estimate file space usage**

```
du -h /path_name
```

-h - human read-able

Answer (score 1):

```
df
```

This Command is only report file system disk space usage

```
du -shx * | sort -rh | head -10
```

But this will show top ten . Try it..